# Implemeting an Interrupt Service Routine in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, interrupt

i am building an app that connects to a router, get some data and inserts the acquired data into a database.

I need to get that data from the router each 30 seconds. And come back to update the Database with the newly acquired data.

I don't know how to implement that timer mechanism (it is similar to the interrupt service routine mechanism).

I am new to Java, Any Help ? Should i use a thread? I read briefly about threads but don't know exactly how they work.

EDIT:
Please note that I have other thing to do in the main . The main is executing several functions. however, every 30 seconds i want to execute a single additional function.

Comment: `ScheduledExecutorService`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleaner way is to schedule a periodic task.

You can use different APIs:

- ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(...)
- Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(..)

Both will execute your code at periodic intervals.

Comment: Thanks for you concern, but i have been trying for a while and i got confused.
ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate takes the first parameter as a Runnable.

while Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate first parameter is callable, 
What are these? i checked the docs and i couldn't understand, do i have to create a new class and pass it there?

Comment: The Runnable/Callable should be implemented by classes (can be anonymous ones) containing the code you need to retrieve the data and update the database. i.e. all the code that must be executed periodically.

Answer (score 2):

As you need to run other code you can do

```
ScheduleExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Data data = getDataFromRouter();
        updateDatabase(data);
    }
}, 0, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

---

Other wise I would have a simple loop like this.

```
while(true) {
    Data data = getDataFromRouter();
    updateDatabase(data);
    Thread.sleep(30 * 1000);
}
```

You need at least one thread, but you start with one.

Comment: I have other thing to do in the main, i don't want to sleep.
That's why i call it interrupt service routine.
The main is executing several functions. however, every 30 seconds i want to execute a single additional function.

Comment: @ShadyAhmed You didn't say that. Can you add those details to the question?

Comment: I can't find the newScheduledExecutorService function

I can find : newScheduledThreadPool instead !

Comment: @ShadyAhmed I have fixed that now.